# javascript function to catch return value

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function result()
{
   return "string";
}
</script>
```

I need to get this string value in to var

var gotresult= ???? how to get here that result value

Comment: This is surely a joke?  If not, I recommend you take a good look at one of the thousands of JavaScript tutorials that will teach you this and other very basic concepts.  You will save yourself (and the SO community) valuable time by learning basic language concepts before coding.

Comment: I would agree with Andy, this question could easily be answered by any javascript tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your HTML to use the correctish MIME type (text/javascript), spell `return` and `function` (thanks Rob) correctly then just replace your question marks with `result()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply talking about `var gotresult = result();`?  Or does that not work for some reason?

Comment: Yes i ma not getting the resul?

Comment: @kumar - how do you know that?

Comment: I am keeping the alert(gotresult).. its showing undefined

thanks

Comment: My funtion is something like this..

function result() {
          $("#Grid1").click(function(e) {
              var row = jQuery(e.target).parent();
              var value= row.attr("id");
              return value;
          });
      }

Comment: As you can see, there are two functions. Your return value is in the inner function and is executed in the click event handler. The outer function just defines the event handler and returns nothing, hence the undefined.

Answer (score 0):

var a;function result(){     return "string";}function setVal(){ var a=result();alert(a)document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=a;}